# LINQ for PostgreSQL or MySQl

Tags: asp.net, mysql, postgresql, mono

I want to host my ASP.NET ( C#) site using Mono. Is there any LINQ like project for PostgreSQL or MySQL that I can use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is DbLinq, already integrated in Mono (since 2.6). Also has an SqlMetal.exe implementation for generation of contexts.